# Adding a populated select dropdown in Laravel Jetstream Registration

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to use Jetstream(Livewire) for authentication. I already succeeded in creating a registration form. However, I wish to change an input field to a select dropdown field based on the data from database. This is the same question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503224/how-to-add-a-new-input-as-a-dropdown-type-and-with-filled-default-options-to-lar) but the answer given was a manual one. I was thinking maybe this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424637/7434025) but it may conflict with the already used return statement(Correct me if I am wrong).

Currently my Fortify/CreateNewUser function:

```
public function create(array $input)
{
    Validator::make($input, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'user_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:125'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        'user_role' => ['required', 'max:20'],
        'user_type' => ['required', 'max:20'],
        'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
    ])->validate();

    return User::create([
        'name' => $input['name'],
        'user_name' => $input['user_name'],
        'email' => $input['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        'user_role' => $input['user_role'],
        'user_type' => $input['user_type'],
    ]);
}
```

Register.blade.php:

```
...
        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-jet-label for="user_role" value="{{ __('Role') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="user_role" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="user_role" required autocomplete="user_role" />
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            <x-jet-label for="user_type" value="{{ __('Type') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="user_type" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="user_type" required autocomplete="user_type" />
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

`CreateNewUser` is only an Action consumed by Fortify. It will perform a validation and create the user when you `POST` the data.

To customize the registration view you need to specify in

**App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider**

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        $myOptions = MyModel::all();
        return view('auth.register', ['myOptions' => $myOptions]);
    });

    // ...
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#registration